# In Hindu religion is there a concept of jinn?

Tags: shiva-purana

I have doubt about jinns and I want to know is there a concept of jinn in Hindu religion.
I want to know who is jinn.

Comment: Jinn is in Islam. There is no concept of jinn in Hinduism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the creation comprises of many parallel realms. And each realm is inhabited by various creatures like yakshas for the yaksha realm. We might not necessarily know about the real existence and validity of jinns/djinn but they might be a spiritual entities like yakshas living in their own plane of existence. However they’re different and well below from plane of the devas and asuras.

Comment: Answers here must be supported with scriptures. Please quote relevant scripture references for your answer. Mandatory it is